# T-String Error PHP

Tags: php

I am very new to php and am working on an assignment. I have pretty much copied the same format as the example our teacher gave us (I just changed the variable names) but I am getting an **unexpected 'fnameempty' (T_STRING), expecting ']'** I'm not sure why this is happening.. Can you please help?

Here is my code :

```
if(isset($_POST['calculate])) {

   $errors =array();

  $fname = $_POST["firstname"];
  $fname = trim($fname);
  $fname = strtolower($fname);
  $fname = ucfirst($fname);
  $lname = $_POST["lastname"];
  $lname = trim($lname);
  $lname = strtolower($lname);
  $lname = ucfirst($lname);
  $hworked = $_POST["hoursworked"];
  $hwage = $_POST["hourlywage"];

//Validating empty elements

  if(empty($fname)) {
    $errors['fnameempty'] = "*";
  }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Missing single quote, should be : `f(isset($_POST['calculate'])) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've forgotten a closing `'` in the `$_POST` array.

```
if(isset($_POST['calculate])) {
```

Comment: It's so funny because I just saw that after I posted. Sorry!!!